# Why can't I display my data filtered to active user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to display only data for the logged in user in my table. I can display everything using objects.all() but when I filter to the active user, it doesn't work. I have tried changing my context to refer to the queryset as a whole but I get an error saying that I can't perform get on a tuple.

If I have the context as is, I get an error saying 'QuerySet object has no attribute 'user'

Models.py:

```
class HealthStats(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    run_distance = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    run_time = models.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'health_stats'
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} | {self.date}"
```

Views.py:

```
def health_history(request):
    queryset = HealthStats.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()
    print(queryset)
    print(type(queryset))
    context = {
            "user": queryset.user_id,
            "weight": queryset.weight,
            "date": queryset.date,
            "run_distance": queryset.run_distance,
            "run_time": queryset.run_time,
        }

    return (request, 'health_hub_history.html', context)
```

health_hub_history.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h1>My Health History</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto text-center p-3">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td>Weight (lbs):</td>
                    <td>Date:</td>
                    <td>Run Distance (km):</td>
                    <td>Run Time (HH:MM:SS):</td>
                </tr>
                {% for stat in queryset %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ stat.user }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stat.weight }} </td>
                    <td>{{ stat.date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stat.run_distance }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stat.run_time }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Ignore the print statements- just trying to figure out the issue, and will remove them once solved. Also aware that the .values() at the end of the queryset declaration is probably wrong- it's there for the same reasons.

I have been going around in circles for a few hours so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
HealthStats.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()
```

The above code gives you a QuerySet object, not your `HealthStats` object. Since `User` is a `ForeignKey` of `HealthStats`, this means that each `User` object can have any number of `HealthStats` objects associated to it (it can have 0, 1, 2, or more stats). This means the function `health_history` should be giving your front end a *list* of `HealthStats` objects.

```
def health_history(request):
    serialized_stats = []
    # `filter` also returns a `QuerySet` object which is already iterable. 
    for stats in HealthStats.objects.filter(user=request.user):
        serialized_stats.append({
            "user": stats.user_id,
            "weight": stats.weight,
            "date": stats.date,
            "run_distance": stats.run_distance,
            "run_time": stats.run_time,
        })
    context = {
        "stats": serialized_stats
    }

    return (request, 'health_hub_history.html', context)
```

You'd probably also need to change your html logic to properly handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your return statement. Try this:

```
return (request, 'health_hub_history.html', {'queryset': queryset})
```

Comment: Also, remove the `.values()` on your queryset.